# How to get Relative Url using Jquery in Sharepoint Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

In my SharePoint site first I want to get Host URL(/Site URL ),and user would enter Relative URL in TextBox.
Then I want to append that relative URL with Host URL Using jquery and need to check that URL before submit action.

How to get Relative URL using jquery in SharePoint Site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `_spPageContextInfo` in your JavaScript.

Usage:

```
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
alert(url);
```

See others here:

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2013-2-_sppagecontextinfo_is_your_new_best_friend.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For Relative Path in sharepoint you can use any of the two:

```
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
```

Or we can use

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext();
var relativeWebUrl = context.get_url();
var fullWebUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + relativeWebUrl ;
```

Answer (score 0):

JSRequest.EnsureSetup();

JSRequest.PathName: returns the relative path.

JSRequest has a few other helpful methods also. See below.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20820.sharepoint-2010-about-jsrequest.aspx