# SPUtility MakeReadOnly for Person fields not including relative url in the read only links

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sputility

I'm using `sputility.js` for making some fields as readonly in my new/edit forms. It works like a charm for all fields except Person fields. The issue with Person fields is when person fields became read-only they are displayed as a link with

`<a href="/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=<USER_ID_HERE>&amp;RootFolder=*"><USER_TITLE_HERE></a>`

this used to throw me access denied error pages on clicking as i do not have access to root web.

I want the link to point to my site collection url something like

`<a href="/sites/site_collection/sub site/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=<USER_ID_HERE>&amp;RootFolder=*"><USER_TITLE_HERE></a>`

which is the correct url to view the profile page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the sputility.js file and found this piece of code

```
 x.done(function (result) {
         // result is an SP.List because that is what we passed to resolve()!
         var htmlText = "";
         for (var i = 0; i < result.users.length; i++) {
            var user = result.users[i];
            if (htmlText !== "") { htmlText += "; "; }
               htmlText += '<a href="/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=' + user.get_id().toString() + '&amp;RootFolder=*">' + user.get_title() + '</a>';
         }
         // finally! send the result to our callback
         return callback(htmlText);
      });
```

I modified the `htmlText+=` line to include the relative url of the current sub-site/site using `_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl` thanks to this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133930/how-to-get-relative-url-using-jquery-in-sharepoint-site) and it works like i expected.

```
x.done(function (result) {
         // result is an SP.List because that is what we passed to resolve()!
         var htmlText = "";
         for (var i = 0; i < result.users.length; i++) {
            var user = result.users[i];
            if (htmlText !== "") { htmlText += "; "; }
               htmlText += '<a href="'+_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+'/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=' + user.get_id().toString() + '&amp;RootFolder=*">' + user.get_title() + '</a>';
         }
         // finally! send the result to our callback
         return callback(htmlText);
      });
```

before i found this solution i was using something like this

```
var changeLink=function(){

                if($('div.sputility-readonly a').length ===1){
                    //console.log('href set. clearing interval');
                    clearInterval(timerInterval);
                    $('div.sputility-readonly a').each(function(){

                    var oldhref=$(this).attr('href');
                    //console.log(oldhref);
                    $(this).attr('href','/sites/site_collection/sub_site'+oldhref);
                    //console.log('new href '+$(this).attr('href'));

                    });
                }
                else{
                    //console.log('href not set yet');
                }
            };
timerInterval=setInterval(changeLink,100);
```

which i used to run whenever i make a Person field as readonly..